# Import Data from Text File into Excel 2019

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

When attempting to convert from TXT to Excel as below inside Excel I can't get desired output.  I have tried it with different delimiter but no luck.
I want to put the text in separate columns in Excel.

Input :

[image]

Desired Output :

[image]

I am getting a preview like below.

[image]

Comment: Some diagrams would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Knowing what version of Excel you are using might help as well, and assuming you have it have you tried Power Query.?

Comment: I'm guessing tab or fixed-width delimited. Power Query should do the job if you can't get the import to work. Otherwise, see if there is a way to get the file in excel format.

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of information for us to help you. But apart basic problems, like delimiter, problems often arise with dates (format ?) and numbers (like "," and "." is it thousands or decimal?) and especially if your locals aren't EN/US.

Comment: @DavidPostill  I have updated my question.

Comment: @BradR I am using Excel 2019.

Comment: @Sylvain I am using EN/US as locals.

Comment: @BlindSpots  Can you show us what you are actually getting?  I've uploaded my screenshot.

Comment: The main issue is with the first 5 rows, although the lack of character delimiters means that you could still have issues with the blank columns depending on the format. If you are generating the data, then you need to delimit it better and place the title row elements properly in columns with other data. For example, [This CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChTRS.png)  imports [with the right columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s30tI.png).  If you are okay with manually importing then [swaglord's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1769961/) works perfectly.

Comment: Is the first column merged?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the import wizard in Excel, located under the **Get & Transform Data** section on the **Data** tab:

[image: Excel screenshot from the Data tab]

From there you have a wizard with preview capabilities that will show you a preliminary output based on your selections:

[image: Excel data import wizard]
After pressing **Load** you'll have your data successfully imported:

[image: Excel screenshot of imported data]

I hope it helps :)